# Detectar ENTER en C pero como tipo entero y no Char

Tags: c

Deseo que al ingresar un numero edad, me detecte si pulse ENTER como número entero para salir del programa.

Yo se que ENTER = '\n' pero se compara con variables tipo char y lo que yo uso es variable entera .

¿Como haría? 
Ya probé con scanf, getchar(), fgets(), todos tratan a ENTER como char , pero no puedo usarlo ya que usaré desigualdades con números enteros al ingresar el número edad

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{

  int edad;
  printf("INGRESAR TU EDAD (entero mayor que cero) : \n");
  scanf("%d",&edad);
  fflush(stdin); 

  if ( edad<18)
    printf("No puedes votar eres menor de edad\n");
  else if ( edad >=18)
    printf(" Si puedes Votar , eres mayor de edad 18\n");
  else ( edad = '\n')
    printf(" Pulsaste ENTER , saliendo ..\n");

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: De hecho char es un número, recuerda que la máquina trabaja con binario, (0 y 1) por lo tanto char es un número que se interpreta como letra de acuerdo a ASCII, lo que podrías hacer es simplemente hacer un casteo `int code = (int) '\n'`

Answer (score 1):

`scanf( "%d" )` espera un número entero. Lo que tu quieres es detectar **una entrada vacía**, o, tal vez, **una conversión incorrecta**.

Una posible solución es comprobar primero si la lectura de un entero es correcta:

```
if( scanf( "%d",&edad) != 0 ) {
  if( edad < 18)
    printf("No puedes votar eres menor de edad\n" );
  else if ( edad >= 18 )
    printf(" Si puedes Votar , eres mayor de edad 18\n" );
}

printf( "Saliendo\n" );
```

Comment: lo que requiero es que si el usuario ademas si pulsa ENTER en vez de un numero , se termine el programa con un mensaje "PUlsaste ENTER ..saliendo del programa" , algo simple pero en C no tanto asi como pense.

Comment: No es tan simple. Para hacer eso que quieres, tienes que ir leyendo 1 a 1 los caracteres que pulsa el usuario (`scanf( "%c" )`), y hacer varias comprobaciones: si son ENTER, si son un número válido, ... Es bastante mas complejo que lo que has mostrado.

Answer (score 1):

Tenes un error en la línea:

```
else ( edad = '\n')
```

Se debería escribir asi:

```
else if( edad == '\n')
```

La función **scanf** no retorna cuando das enter hasta que hayas introducir algun caracter diferente de '\n'.

El '\n' en numero es 10.

Comment: gracias , lo he corregido else if( edad == '\n')  pero me sigue saltando a nueva Linea vacia cada vez que pulso ENTER ! ;

Comment: Es que la función scanf() funciona así, no retorna nunca un '\n'. Primero tenes que introducir un valor, y cuando presionas ENTER, la funcion scanf() retorna ese valor, pero nunca el '\n'.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que `scanf()`, cuando se usa para leer enteros, flotantes o cadenas, considera los espacios y los retornos de carro como delimitadores, por lo que no los lee, sino que los *espera*. Me explico. Si está esperando por un entero, leerá e ignorará todos los espacios y retornos de carro que se encuentre en la entrada estándar hasta encontrar el primer dígito. Después leerá y procesará los dígitos hasta encontrar otro espacio o retorno de carro y ahí se detendrá. Si en la entrada estándar no hay nada, esperará a que haya algo. No retornará hasta haber leido el entero.

Eso tiene los siguientes efectos. Supongamos que el usuario escribe `"   123\n"` (tres espacios, tres dígitos y pulsa ENTER)

- Se saltará los espacios (comportamiento deseable), leerá el entero 123 (comportamiento esperado), y se detendrá ahí, retornando y dejando el retorno de carro sin leer en la entrada estándar (lo que puede ser un problema porque el siguiente intento de leer de la entrada estándar se encontrará ese \n lo primero).

Supongamos que en cambio el usuario pulsa simplemente ENTER

- Se saltará el \n como si fuera un espacio y buscará que haya después un dígito. No hay nada después, de modo que **se queda esperando hasta que lo haya**. El usuario puede seguir pulsando ENTER que no va a cambiar nada, pues todos esos \n serán ignorados y seguirá esperando por un dígito.

En definitiva **scanf()** no es la función que necesitas aquí.

### Solución

Hay diferentes formas de resolver el problema pero creo que la más simple puede ser utilizar `fgets()` para leer *la línea completa* que el usuario teclee. Esta función sólo se quedará esperando si la entrada estándar está vacía. Entonces leerá todo lo que el usuario teclee hasta encontrar un retorno de carro (y leerá también ese retorno de carro) y dejará todo lo leído en el buffer que le indiques (un array de chars). Dicho más brevemente: **lee una línea completa**.

Una vez leída la línea es sencillo ver si el usuario tecleó simplemente ENTER o algo más. En el primero caso el buffer contendrá un solo carácter "\n". Puedes usar `strcmp()` para comparar el buffer con la cadena `"\n"`, o usar `strlen()` para ver si la longitud del buffer es 1 (contiene solo un byte, el retorno de carro). En el segundo caso contendrá más de 1 byte. Finalmente puedes usar `atoi()` para convertir la entrada del usuario en un entero para el segundo caso.

Demo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    char buffer[80];

    printf("Introduzca un numero o enter: ");

    fgets(buffer, 79, stdin);
    if (strcmp(buffer, "\n")==0) {
        printf("Has pulsado enter");
    } else {
        n = atoi(buffer);
        printf("Has introducido el entero %d\n", n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Notas**

1. Es necesario dar un tamaño al buffer, pero no sabemos cuánto va a teclear el usuario antes del ENTER. He puesto 80, lo que obliga a pasar a `fgets()` el número 79 para decirle que una vez haya leido 79 caracteres sin encontrar un retorno de carro, retorne de todas formas, para evitar un buffer overflow.
2. `fgets()` añadirá como último carácter un byte de valor 0 para que actúe como terminador de cadena. Por eso indiqué un byte menos del tamaño del buffer.
3. Se presupone que el usuario va a teclear un entero válido. Pero realmente podría teclear cualquier cosa. Por ejemplo "hola". `atoi()` devuelve 0 en caso de que no pueda interpretar como entero la cadena (y pone el valor `EINVAL` en la variable `errno`, por si quieres verificarlo).
4. Todo esto sólo sirve si el usuario teclea un solo número en la línea. Si quisieras leer varios en la misma línea tendrías que procesarla separando por los espacios (con `strtok()`).